# How to understand the padding rules on cloud TPU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, padding, google-cloud-tpu, tensorflow-xla

Cloud TPU has two padding rules on batch_size and feature_size of convolution operations, to minimize memory overhead and maximize computational efficiency (from [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting/trouble-tf#memory-tensor-padding)).

- The total batch size should be a multiple of 64 (8 per TPU core), and feature dimensions should be a multiple of 128,

or

- The total batch size should be a multiple of 1024 (128 per TPU core), and feature dimensions should be a multiple of 8.

If batch size and feature don't conform to the rules, padding occurs. According to the profiling results, the second one (batch_size/core -> 128, feature/core -> 8) is used.

I want to ask the rationale for these rules. As far as I know, the MXU unit is 128x128 systolic array since TPUv2. Why not pad both pre core batch size and feature to 128?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that the MXU unit is 128x128, and padding both per core batch size and feature to 128 will achieve the best memory usage. Actually in the link you referred to, the last paragraph says

```
Using a batch size of 1024 and feature dimensions that
are a multiple of 128 results in the best efficiency, 
although this may not be possible for all models.
```

This, plus the two rules you mentioned here can be interpreted as: If possible, set batch size to be multiples of 1024 (128 per core), and feature dimension to be multiples of 128. Otherwise, try to match at least one of the two conditions, i.e. batch size to be multiples of 1024, or feature dimension to be multiples of 128.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if we can only make one size a multiple of 128, why do we need to make the other size a multiple of 8 at the same time? In addition, the sizes of per core batch and feature dimensions are both related to the column size of MXU, and there seems to be no requirement related to the row size of MXU. I'm still confused.

Comment: The "layout" section in [this cloud tpu doc](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tpus)  mentions "The structure of the MXU hardware, a 128x128 systolic array, and the design of TPU’s memory subsystem, which prefers dimensions that are multiples of 8, are used by the XLA compiler for tiling efficiency." So MXU is 128x128, and XLA tiling works 8x128. Here are more details about XLA tiling: https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tiled_layout